# Unknown filesystem error at boot

Tags: boot, grub2

After upgrading 12.04 LTS kernel from 3.2.0-48 to 3.2.0-51-generic, GRUB stops at startup with message `Unknown filesystem`. Pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> it boots normally.

Booting to a previous kernel works nice. Can anyone help me to get rid of this error?

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found a soultion:

Type

```
uname -r
```

Remember the kernel that you are currently on.
Now remove the OTHER kernels:
To remove a kernel versions, open up Synaptic Package Manager, found in the System > Administration menu.

When it opens up, type the kernel version that you want to remove in the Quick search text field. The first few numbers should suffice.
[image]

For each of the entries associated with the old kernel (e.g. linux-headers-2.6.32-21 and linux-image-2.6.32-21-generic), right-click and choose Mark for Complete Removal.
[image]

Click the Apply button in the toolbar and then Apply in the summary window that pops up. Close Synaptic Package Manager.

Now type in the Command Line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You should have the latest kernel installed now.
Update Grub:
    sudo update-grub

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I do not dare to remove the kernel that work and trust the one causing the problem. Peter

Comment: uname -r will show you the kernel that you are on right now(the working one). Remove all of them EXCEPT this!

Comment: I can boot both kernels. The only problem is, that the newest pauses booting process with message about unknown filesystem. I prefer to fix the problem, rather than using old kernel.

Comment: you are not using old kernel. did you even read my answer? you are unninstall it temporarly so you can reinstall it. the problem with your kernel may by a bad package or something that is causing this and you are reinstalling it.

Comment: Now I can understand what you have in minds. Idea to remove and then reload the **latest** kernel may solve the problem. Once again: thank you for your efforts!

Comment: **Problem solved!**